# Java : Accessing Hidden Interface Field

Tags: java, interface, field

How to access an interface's field (which is by default public, static and final) using the implementing class's instance (`this` or `super` or instanceName if possible) if the field is hidden?

```
package mypack;

public interface MyInterface {
    String str = "MyInterface.str";
    String inheritanceTest = "inherited";
}
```

The field that i want to access is `str`

The other field `inheritanceTest` is to prove that interface fields are in fact inherited *(unlike interface static methods)*

```
package mypack;

public class Child implements MyInterface {

//  Hiding the field
    String str = "Child.str";


//  Access test.
    public String getParentStr() {
        String result = "";

//      result = MyInterface.super.str; // No enclosing instance of the type MyInterface is accessible in scope
//      result = super.str; //str cannot be resolved or is not a field

        return result;
    }

//  A method to check if the field is inherited or not.
    public String getInheritedString() {
        return this.inheritanceTest;
    }
}
```

**Notes**

1. I know that it is discouraged to access static members using an instance instead of accessing it statically (`Type.staticMemberNameOrSignature`).
2. As shown, static interface methods are not inherited while static interface fields are inherited.
3. Non commented lines do not generate any compile-time errors.
4. Commented lines which are trying to assign a value to the variable `result` are the ones generating compile-time errors (Added to the line)
5. I am **not** asking about how to access the interface field **statically**.

**Clarifying The Question**

Is it possible to access an interfaces field that have been hidden by the implementing class **using an instance** (instance keywords like `this` or `super`) of the class?

Comment: `return MyInterface.str;`

Comment: The fact that it is an interface doesn't matter.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Question updated.

Comment: The answer remains the same. The quote from the JLS covers all options. Only two of those are relevant for interfaces, fully qualified name and cast to interface.

Comment: The answer means that it can **only** be **statically** accessed. thus impossible to be accessed otherwise. Correct?

Comment: Another note : static superclass fields can be accessed using the keyword `super`

Comment: As far I can tell from the JLS, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to access an interfaces field that have been hidden by the implementing class using an instance (instance keywords like this or super) of the class?

Yes. Instead of using this or super, just use interface name to access it.

```
MyInterface.str
```